# Why is it showing error inspite of the fact that I downloaded the idle and idle3 for python in virtual box?

Tags: linux, python3

IDLE Installation error for python 3 in Linux
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KTeF.jpg)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots (or worse, photos of screen). Copy/paste text.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell from the screenshot, but it looks like you are trying to run Idle from within a command line only deployment of Linux. Idle requires a window manager to be installed. 
The error is reporting that it cannot find a window manager to launch the GUI.

You will need to install a version of Linux with Xserver or something similar installed.